# PHP array not updating

Tags: php, arrays

There is probably something dumb I am doing wrong here.

```
public function get_scores($id)
{
    $results = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE comp_id = $id";
    $rows = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        if($row->confirmed_id) {
            $results[$row->uid] += $row->score;
        }
    }
    sort($results);
    return $results;
}
```

So basically what I am trying to do is add all of the users scores in the database and return them in order of rank.  confirmed->id is just a check to make sure the score has been confirmed (and thus is addable to their total score).  I am basically trying to just make an associative array where the key is the users ID, and the score of each question they have in the database is added on.  The query works fine, and $row-uid and $row->score both return the correct thing for every row, but $results[] never has anything added to it.   If I even change it just to something silly like $results[3] = 0 at top, and then $results[3]++ or += 1 in the for loop, it doesn't add anything to $results[3].

EDIT: Problem solved. Indeed was something dumb -- confirmed_id was set to null by my partner when he reran our database after I had previously set it all to 1. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Can you just check without '+'   ie. $results[$row->uid] = $row->score;

Comment: What is the value of `$row->confirmed_id` for each row? Is it ever truthy?

Comment: You have something against curly braces or using aggregate SQL functions? Your code could benefit from both :)

Comment: Sigh. Embarrassing.  My coding partner set them all to NULL in our database for some reason.  After I had all set them to 1.  What a dumb problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding to $results[something] before it exists.  You need to create it in the first case and then only increment it once it exists.

Comment: Well it is at least **a** problem.

Comment: This isn't -- I have added in $results[3] = 0 at the top, and it doesn't fix it previously.  [3] is my test case that all current uids are.

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  Initially $results[anyid] is undefined.  It doesn't exist.  Thus when you do $results[anyid] += 3, you are doing $results[anyid] = undefined + 3.  Which won't do what you want.

Comment: Right -- which is why I was saying at the top of my code I was setting it $result[3] to 0, since I know all of my current id's are 3 anyway.  So it would be doing $result[3] = 0 + x. Thanks though =]

Comment: The fact remains that the code you posted has a blatant defect.  So since you keep insisting it isn't wrong I'm downvoting the question until you fix it.

Comment: Expanding on my first comment; Whilst PHP will trigger an `E_NOTICE` error for the undefined array index, it will also silently create it and treat the value as `0` in the addition operation, ergo, probably not the problem here.

Comment: @Ken: `null + 1` evaluates to 1, and `$result[$x] += 1` is equivalent to `$result[$x] = $result[$x] + 1`.  Even if the index doesn't exist yet, it will after the statement runs.  The OP's code is ugly, but it works, and it does what it should.

Comment: Alright well if you want to rely on that kind of behavior.  I know I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "+=" operation from the code. Check with this.

```
public function get_scores($id)
{
    $results = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE comp_id = $id";
    $rows = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
    foreach($rows as $row)
        if($row->confirmed_id)
            $results[$row->uid] = $row->score;
    sort($results);
    return $results;
}
```

Your previous operation is similar to

```
$results[$row->uid] = $results[$row->uid] + $row->score;
```

So it will not add values to your row.